# MySQL - Like with index

Tags: mysql, like

I found many question, But no solutions.

An index can not be used to speed up queries where the search criteria starts with a wildcard:

```
LIKE '%text%'
```

An index can (and might be, depending on selectivity) used for search terms of the form:

```
LIKE 'text%'
```

So this means I simply cant use a full wildcard in a big table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly. Which is why some databases use alternative indexing mechanisms for text. SQL Server has a full text indexing capability that works by breaking the string into WORDS, removing bad ones (like "in" in english - happens too often) and then uses a different syntax for finding words in the text index.

Standard SQL Indices are simply not suited for the task.

MySQL, from a 30 second run in google, also seems to have a [full text search mechanism](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: thx, I need support for more than full words